# SqlConnection type is not defined

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, sqlconnection

I'm trying to connect my Web Application with an Azure database using  `System.Data.SqlClient` and `SqlConnection`.
I configured my web.config (`<connectionStrings>`) and referenced `System.Data` but the error still there.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    Public Class BaseDatos

        Private conexion As New SqlConnection
```

> BC30002 Visual Basic The type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.

Comment: .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Comment: .net framework @jmcilhinney

Comment: Instead of typing `SqlConnection` there, try typing the fully qualified name and see if and where Intellisense doesn't tell you what you expect, e.g. if you get as far as `System.Data.SqlClient.` then what does Intellisense tell you is available?

Comment: Intellisense says "the declaration of imports is not necessary" about Imports System.Data.SqlClient, but then is giving an error when I declare SqlConnection saying "Is not defined type SqlConnection", so I'm stucked because I don't have access to the DB. @jmcilhinney

Comment: None of that is relevant to what I said.  Do what I said to do and answer the question I asked.  If you need to delete the namespace import (which I doubt) then do that.

Comment: The intellisense says that i need to import "System.Data.dll", but when I do an error appears "VisualBasicAddImportCodeFixProvider detected an error and its disabled", and the error still there.   @jmcilhinney

Comment: Solved!! I instaled System.Data.SqlClient for the NuGet package manager and the error fixed. Thanks for your reply. @jmcilhinney

Comment: It sounds to me like you are actually targeting .NET Core rather than .NET Framework.  The `SqlConnection` class is declared in the *System.Data.dll* assembly in the .NET Framework and in the *System.Data.SqlClient.dll* assembly in .NET Core. I just tried adding that NuGet package to a .NET Framework project and it wouldn't even let me, via the GUI at least.  I can't see how a .NET Framework project could possibly not have access to that type unless something is genuinely broken.